# PHP nested foreach generating duplicates

Tags: php, foreach, lightbox, nested

I know this has been posted a million times over but I cant find an example where the same item was being called for the same use but with different values. I am using lightbox and I need my `<a>` to pull in the size=full and my `<img>` to pull in the size=thumbnail. I am successfully doing this but my nested foreach statements are casing duplicates.

```
<?php 
    $dyno_images = rwmb_meta( 'gallery-images', 'type=image_advanced&size=thumbnail' );
    $dyno_images_lrg = rwmb_meta( 'gallery-images', 'type=plupload_image&size=full' ); 
?>
<?php 
    foreach ( $dyno_images_lrg as $dyno_image_lrg ) {
        foreach ( $dyno_images as $dyno_image ) {
            echo '<figure class="gallery-item"><div class="gallery-icon landscape"><a href="'.$dyno_image_lrg['url'].'" class="fancybox image" rel="gallery"><img src="'.$dyno_image['url'].'" aria-describedby="gallery-1-584" class="attachment-full"></a></div></figure>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that each item in `$dyno_images_lrg` corresponds to an item in `$dyno_images`.

In that case you only want to loop once and pick out the corresponding item:

```
foreach ( $dyno_images_lrg as $key => $dyno_image_lrg ) {
    $dyno_image = $dyno_images[$key];
    //Snipped for brevity - rest of the code should remain the same
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Except I think you meant =>, which is what worked for me ;)

Comment: @Heather Whoops, I did mean `=>` now fixed.

Comment: @Heather, you should have accepted this as the answer.

Comment: @0yeoj It wouldn't let me till later and then I forgot. Thanks for the reminder.